# Ionic exporting project to apk

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic platform, I am learning it. I created a project. I am facing some problem to generate apk. My OS is Windows. I already installed Android Studio and JDK 10.0.2, JRE 10.0.2. When I run `ionic cordova build --release android` this command. It shows....

```
Android Studio project detected  
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Mithun\AppData\Local\Android\sdk  
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2
(node:9708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater  
    at C:\ionic\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:370:19
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: If you are using **Ionic 4** then goto this link [Ionic 4 exporting project to APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357536/ionic-4-exporting-project-to-apk-how-to-build-apk-from-a-ionic-4-framework-sour)

Answer (score 0):

you need JDK 1.8 or greater

> Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

not JDK 10.0.2

download link for 64bit windows

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: i am not getting you !

Comment: install the jdk 1.8x from the link it will fix the problem

Comment: should i remove jdk 10.0.2. Why it shows 1.8 or greater ?

Comment: currently I have 10.0.2 which is greater

Comment: bro, it shows **Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.**

Comment: you did't install jdk properly or did not set up the env path

Comment: i did everything

Comment: I'm trying to fix out this from 2 days back

Comment: make a fresh install of java jre and jdk

Comment: I did that. firstly removed previous file. Then followed your instruction